# Socket.IO just stopped working on my Electron App

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron

I have an electron app that has been running at 3 sites for just over a month now.  The Electron app connects to a socket.io server using node's socket.io-client.  The connections were all still okay on 30 Sep, but none have been working since 1 Oct.  In an attempt to try to isolate the problem I wrote a "test.js" with the follow simple code;

```
  const io = require("socket.io-client");
  const client = io("wss://myserver.com");
  console.log('check 1', client.connected); // returns false as expected
  client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('check 2', client.connected); // returns true after about a second
  });
```

When I run "node test.js" all works okay. The first check returns false and the second check returns true. However, when I copy/paste the exact code into the Electron app and run "electron ." (or "npm start") I get the first check returning false as expected and no second check returning anything. Bearing in mind this all worked 4 days ago on 3 separate sites. The test.js is in the same folder as the electron app.js and calls the same instance of socket.io-client.

Any ideas as to what I could try next or what the problem is?

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Try adding some more event listeners like `client.on('connect_error', ...` or `client.on('disconnect', function(reason){....`.

Comment: Also check if anything on firewall/antivirus etc. changed (try disabling  for short amount of time and test.. ) . Also make sure that `Windows Feature => websockets` are enabled.. Google will help^^.

Comment: Same error here. I have an electron app that has been running 3 years without any issue. Today (Oct. 5 2021) electron websockets just stopped working.
After enabling Windows Feature => websockets (thanks @SilvanBregy ) it started throwing errors in debug console, but still no connection to the server :(

Comment: @IgorVujovic - It was a frustrating time, what eventually worked for me was deleting node-modules folder and package-lock.json.  Then changing socket.io-client version to "latest" in package.json and running npm install and ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild. I hope this helps.

Comment: Updating socket.io-client version and compiling using latest electronjs helped. Thanks @SilvanBregy and daniel-van-eeden